# ajax response comparison to string

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net

I am using this ajax code to get a 'YES' or a 'NO' value back from a VB function.

```
 $.ajax(
                {

                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'validateWorkorder',
                    data: str,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        alert(data)
                        var result = data
                        alert(result)
                        if (result == "NO")
                        {
                            alert('Workorder cannot be found in Printline database.');
                            $('#textWorkorder').css('background-color', 'red');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#textWorkorder').css('background-color', 'white');

                        }
                    },

                    error: function (xhr, errorType, exception)
                    {
                        var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText;
                        alert(errorMessage);
                    }
                }
                );
```

If you notice in the success area, I have two alerts that result "YES" or "NO" depending on what I send to the function via json. However, when I try to compare 
    If (result == "NO")
there seems to always be a false condition even though 'data' does in fact = NO in my testing.

What am I doing wrong and why so I can learn.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible the ajax could be getting extra characters, either spaces or line breaks, I used to have this issue alot when I used to use ajax for string literals, i've since started using xml formatting for all my responses and it just makes life easier.

Comment: interesting Wobbles. When i set the return as json it does error that the is an extra line

Comment: this just fixed it: var result = $.trim(data)

Comment: Wobbles can you throw your comment in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible the ajax could be getting extra characters, either spaces or line breaks, I used to have this issue alot when I used to use ajax for string literals, i've since started using xml formatting for all my responses and it just makes life easier.